Bad hyperref anchors for appendix sections using llncs
I want to use LNCS's document class llncs with an appendix, but encountered a problem: links to sections lead to the correct section number, but to the main body instead of the appendix.
In the example below, the page numbers in the TOC are wrong. Clicking on "Appendix section" leads to "Main body section" (the same section number but in the body instead of the appendix), and clicking on "B" leads to "Another main body section (same). Hilariously, links to the third section in the appendix work correctly, because there is no third section in the main body.
How do I make this behave correctly? I tried digging through the llncs.cls file but my TeX-fu was not strong enough to figure this out.
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

%% Body
\section{Main body section}
\label{1}
Hello \ref{a2}
\clearpage
World

\section{Another main body section}
\label{2}
Hello \ref{a3}
\clearpage
World

\clearpage
\appendix

\section{Appendix section}
\label{a1}
Hello
\clearpage
World

\section{Another appendix section}
\label{a2}
Hello
\clearpage
World

\section{Another appendix section}
\label{a3}
Hello
\clearpage
World

\end{document}



Did you look in the log? There is a hint. See if it helps if you add \renewcommand\theHsection{\thesection.appendix} after \appendix, basically the internal anchor name is not uniq. The redef might help. Not sure if this is the proper solution.

Thank you, this solved the issue! If you wish to add it as an answer I'll accept it. (Or I can add it myself if you don't want to.)

Ulrike is the one who knows hyperref the best. Go by her recommendation

The class is a bit unfair to hyperref: it is based on article and expect sections to be used as top level commands but defines the \chapter command for the tableofcontents and that confuses the hyperref patch.
On the other side, article should redefine \theHsection anyway and not leave that to hyperref, so I will suggest a change for article.cls.
In the meantime you can do something like this (any redefinition of \theHsection that makes it unique in the appendix will do):
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\title{Test}
\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/before}{\gdef\theHsection{\Alph{section}}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%% Body
\section{Main body section}
\label{1}
Hello \ref{a2}
\clearpage
World

\section{Another main body section}
\label{2}
Hello \ref{a3}
\clearpage
World

\clearpage
\appendix

\section{Appendix section}
\label{a1}
Hello
\clearpage
World

\section{Another appendix section}
\label{a2}
Hello
\clearpage
World

\section{Another appendix section}
\label{a3}
Hello
\clearpage
World

\end{document}

